# Loading XML through Java and making part of HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, android, xml, dom, webview

I am developing a WebView based Android application. This application is very responsive and fast on major Android versions i.e. 2.3 onwards but it's very slow on Amazon Kindle fire. One of the reasons for this sluggish behavior is it's reading lots of xml files (40-50) to load contents in a single html page and there are also hundreds of images per page.

One solution that I can think of is to read and parse xml files using native Android APIs (in a thread) and then incorporate the parsed xml into the html page. Could anybody please tell me how to use Java object in JavaScript? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you currently parse the XML files with JS?

Comment: To be more precise, I am loading and parsing xml files using Ajax and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**For your parse slowness issue**
Have a JS-> Java Interface to parse in Java and have those XML data fetch operations in Java too.

**Displaying too many images slowness**
Display only selective set of images as you scroll. Displaying all the images together puts a heavy load on the browser rendering. So use a Lazy Load (jQuery plugin) - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload to only load when the user scrolls.